# Запрещать явно наследоваться от object

Tags: python, python-3.x, статический-анализ, pylint, flake8

**Описание проблемы:**

В Python-2.x, если нужно было объявить [new-style класс](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/), приходилось явно наследоваться от `object`, например:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
```

В Python-3.x классы неявно объявляются наследниками `object`, можно написать просто:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
```

Но, оба варианта объявления класса будут работать в 3.x.

**Вопрос:**

Можно ли, с помощью статического анализа кода и инструментов вроде `pylint`, `flake8` запретить первый, устаревший вариант объявления класса?

<sub>Пожалуйста, не судите строго - это мой первый вопрос на ru.SO.</sub>

Comment: Редко к нам захаживают пользователи из других земель, да ещё прославленные там. Надеюсь, это хороший знак - мы развиваемся, ура! И добро пожаловать, конечно :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для начала проверим это вручную, дабы примерно понять, что именно делает PyLint. Пример файла для проверки (пускай будет `tester.py`):

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass


class MyAnotherClass(MyClass):
    pass


class MyNormalClass:
    pass


class MyStringInteger(str, int, object):
    pass
```

Теперь пример скрипта, который и будет заниматься проверкой исходника:

```
import ast

MODULE_PATH = "tester.py"
with open(MODULE_PATH, "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    MODULE_AS_STRING = f.read()

root = ast.parse(source=MODULE_AS_STRING)
nodes_gen = ast.walk(root)
for node in nodes_gen:
    if type(node) is ast.ClassDef:
        print("Yo! Found class definition. Classname: ", node.name)
        bases_list = []
        for bc in node.bases:
            bases_list.append(bc.id)
        print("Base classes:", ', '.join(bases_list))
```

Результат:

```
Yo! Found class definition. Classname:  MyClass
Base classes: object
Yo! Found class definition. Classname:  MyAnotherClass
Base classes: MyClass
Yo! Found class definition. Classname:  MyNormalClass
Base classes: 
Yo! Found class definition. Classname:  MyStringInteger
Base classes: str, int, object
```

Скрипт открывает модуль как текст, затем преобразовывает в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево (AST) и уже с этим деревом можно работать. Pylint работает примерно таким же образом, однако использует [NodeVisitor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) для путешествия по дереву. Этот Visitor вызывает определнные методы, когда находит элемент. Например, вызывает `visit_classdef`, когда натыкается на определение класса. Вызывает `visit_callfunc`, когда натыкается на вызов функции. И так далее - константы, `assert`, математические операции и все, что только есть в языке. Для того, чтобы приделать себе модное `pylint` дополнение нужно написать такой класс (файл pylint_plugin.py):

```
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker, utils
from pylint.interfaces import IAstroidChecker

BASE_ID = 56

def register(linter):
    print("Registering pylint plugin...")
    linter.register_checker(MyClassChecker(linter))
    print("Yo! Registered!")


class MyClassChecker(BaseChecker):

    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker
    MESSAGE_ID = "bad_classes_with_object"

    msgs = {
        'W%d01' % BASE_ID: ("%s classname has some problems with object...",
                        MESSAGE_ID,
                        "Please rewrite")
    }

    # Обязательно необходимо определить этот аттрибут
    name = "object_inheritance_checker"

    @utils.check_messages(MESSAGE_ID)
    def visit_classdef(self, node):
        for bc in node.bases:
        # Внимание - это уже класс astroid.Name
        if bc.name == 'object':
            print("MY CLASSES PRINT! YO!", node)
            self.add_message(msg_id=self.MESSAGE_ID, node=node, args=node.name)
```

Документация `pylint` не блистает, поэтому я не совсем уверен в правильности плагина и написан он "лишь бы работало" (увы). Для того, чтобы написать свой собственный понадобятся следующие вещи (все это описано по адресу https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide/custom_checkers.html):

1. Функция `register(linter)`, которая скажет, что необходимо использовать дополнительные проверки. В этой функции необходимо вызывать `linter.register_checker` для всех дополнительных проверок.
2. Собственно, классы проверяльщики (Visitor'ы). В этих классах обязательно должны быть определены:

   - Имя (аттрибут `name`) - собственно, имя проверки.
   - Приоритет (аттрибут `priority`) должен быть меньше нуля.
   - Словарь сообщений `msgs`. Этот словарь должен иметь такую структуру: `msgs = {'message-id': ('displayed-message', 'message-symbol', 'message-help')}`. `message_id` должен быть уникален и не конфликтовать с существующими. Он состоит из идентификатора - `C, W, E, F, R`, означающих `Convention - соглашение, Warning - предупреждение, Error - ошибка, Fatal - ужасная ошибка and Refactoring - переделать`. Также message_id состоит из 4-хзначного номера. Почти все проекты, что я видел используют какой-нибудь свой `BASE_ID` и номер сообщения. Т.о. `message_id` ограничен 5 символами. К чему это было сделано - немыслимо.
   - Собственно, сами функции, проверяющие определенные конструкции в коде. Уже упоминавшиеся `visit_<node_name>` Нам нужно проверять определение класса и его наследников - так сделаем же именно это. В самой функции необходимо обратить внимание, что `pylint` использует не родной модуль [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html), а модуль [`astroid`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid/1.0.0) и соответственно все узлы именно из [`astroid`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/astroid/1.0.0).

Если все это было сделано - плагин готов и его можно вызвать как-то так:

```
pylint --load-plugins "pylint_plugin" tester.py
```

В конце будет отчет вот такого вида:

```
Messages

--------


+------------------------+------------+
|message id              |occurrences |
+========================+============+
|missing-docstring       |5           |
+------------------------+------------+
|too-few-public-methods  |3           |
+------------------------+------------+
|bad_classes_with_object |2           |
+------------------------+------------+
```

2 плохих класса - как и было описано.

Comment: Спасибо за очень подробное описание и потраченное время! Попробую оформить этот рул по Вашим инструкциям. Однозначно, с меня премия.